# Route to application stopped working in OpenShift 4.6

Tags: openshift

I have an application running in Openshift 4.6.

The pod is running, I can exec into it and check this, I can port-forward to it and access it.

when trying to access the application, I get the error message:

> Application is not available The application is currently not serving
> requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still
> starting.
>
> Possible reasons you are seeing this page:
>
> The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and
> that a route matching this hostname exists.
>
> The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL
> path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the
> desired path.
>
> Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the
> resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs,
> etc) have at least one pod running.

Answer (score 4):

There could be multiple reasons for this. You don't really provide enough debugging details to get to the next steps. But I generally find it helps to work backwards through the request.

- *Can you access the pod via port-forward?* You say you've already tested this, but I include it for completeness. But I also mention it to make sure that you are verifying that you are serving the protocol you expect. If you have HTTPS passthrough on the route, but you are serving HTTP from your pod, there will obviously be a problem.
- *Can you access the pod providing your service from outside the pod (but within the cluster)?* e.g. create a debug pod and see if you can connect to your service with curl some other client. If this doesn't work, you may not be exposing the ports of your pod correctly. Check the pod definitions.
- *Can you access the service from outside the pod (but within the cluster)?* e.g. from your debug pod, use the service directly. If this doesn't work, you may have the selector on your service wrong. Or some other problem with your service. Check the service definition.
- *Can you access the route from inside the cluster?* e.g. from your debug pod, try to use the full route URL. If this doesn't work, you've narrowed it down to the route definition. Again, HTTPS vs HTTP can sometimes be a mistake here such as having HTTPS passthrough when your service doesn't support HTTPS. Check the route definition.
- *Finally, try accessing the route eternally.* Which is sounds like you have already tried. But if you've narrowed it down such that your route works internally you've determined that the problem is something in the external network. It doesn't sound like this is your problem, but it's something to keep in mind.