# When I try to access my nginx deployment pods in azure redhat openshift it shows error in browser like below

Tags: openshift, redhat, aro

> Application is not available The application is currently not serving
> requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still
> starting.
>
> Possible reasons you are seeing this page:
>
> The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and
> that a route matching this hostname exists. The host exists, but
> doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed
> correctly and that the route was created using the desired path. Route
> and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources
> exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have
> at least one pod running.

Comment: Please provide more details. Starting with how the pods are deployed, details of the containers, logs for the containers, information about what is actual running, and what debugging you have already tried. The only thing  your error message is telling us is that that the route can't be processed. There's no way to know from what you have provided why that is: a missing service, a missing pod, a failed container, permissions ...

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Route to application stopped working in OpenShift 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571443/route-to-application-stopped-working-in-openshift-4-6/72589288#72589288) for a similar question. Fundamentally, the error message you are seeing explains itself "the application is not available". You need to do some debugging to figure out why.

Paraphrasing my answer on the other question:

1. Verify that your application's pod (or pods) are running.
2. Check the logs of the pods to see if they are failing.
3. Check that the pods are able to serve traffic on the expected ports with something like port-forward
4. Check that the service exists, it's selector is correct, and is pointed at the right ports. Test the service's port from within the cluster.
5. Check that the route is pointing at the right service. Verify the ports are SSL-characteristics are right. (e.g. don't be expecting HTTPS traffic from and HTTP service and vice versa). Verify the route from within the cluster.
6. Check the behavior from outside the cluster.